# Displaying both video and image in a single view element

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm attempting to create an Instagram styled app and cannot figure out a way to display media in a UITableView the way they do (either video or image in a single view). I know it most likely is a custom implementation of UIWebView or something of the sort, however I have no idea where to even begin writing a subclass like that. Things I've already tried include:

1. Using a UIWebView (massive memory leak, even when adding/removing the views programmatically).
2. Adding either UIImageView or UIWebView depending on whether or not it was a video or image (again had a memory leak)
3. Searching the internet for a possible way to do this

If anyone could help me out that would be awesome! FYI the media I am using is grabbed straight from my server, there is no data being gathered from a popular source such as YouTube, Flickr, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think they use [UICollectionview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) as it allows for better customization of a table.

In terms of images and videos, use [UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimageview_class/Reference/Reference.html) to display all your images and [MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to play videos.

Comment: My issue is that the cell is being reused. Everything I've tried results in a massive amount of memory being used. As for MPMoviePlayerController wouldn't that use a ton of memory as well having to download every video?

Comment: reusing cells is good practice, what do you mean by massive memory? remember your working with rich media content...

Comment: I mean as in downloading each individual data file so it can be displayed in the corresponding view. I would assume that would be the only logical way to do it however Instagram can apparently load hundreds of media files without slowing down or crashing. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: I think Instagram doesn't try to load your video or image as soon as the cell is displayed. They display a custom "data loading" view first, while they download the media. As soon as the media is ready to use, they remove the "data loading" view from the cell, and replace it with a UIImageView or a MPMoviePlayerController and load the already downloaded image or video from memory (if the cell is still visible)